# Parallel.Foreach - NULL Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to learn how to use the TPL. I've done a fair bit of reading on the subject but I can't understand why the following code sample breaks, and the one after works?

I've got a unit test running to count the records wrote, and also reading the outputted file in to double check.

Failing:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(featuresLocation), s =>
            {
                var feature = CreateFeature(s);
                if (feature.HasValue)
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            lock (_locker)
                            {
                                featuresWriter.WriteLine(feature.Value);
                                RecordsWrote++;
                            }
                        }));
                }
            });

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); // Breaks
```

Working:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(featuresLocation), s =>
            {
                var feature = CreateFeature(s);
                if (feature.HasValue)
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            lock (_locker)
                            {
                                featuresWriter.WriteLine(feature.Value);
                                RecordsWrote++;
                            }
                        }));
                }
            });

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.Where(x => x != null).ToArray()); // Works
```

Comment: Where is the code for the tasks variable?

Comment: I've changed the question, the tasks variable is within the same scope as the foreach and the waitall

Comment: Starting a task that does everything inside a lock() isn't the most optimal, esp as the calling code is already in a ForEach. I would drop those Tasks.

Comment: I don't understand why you create tasks inside Paralell Loop? Can't it be synchronous?

Comment: Thanks Sriram, that makes sense.. I wasn't really gaining anything from creating a task to write to the file :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

Parallel.ForEach( 
{   
   tasks.Add(...);
});
```

This use of `List<Task> tasks` is not thread-safe. You are seeing `null` elements where they shouldn't be but run this a little longer and you may see other symptoms and exceptions as well. The behavior is undefined.

Protect the access to `tasks` , replace it with a `ConcurrentBag` or, my choice, drop those Tasks altogether. You are getting enough parallelism from the `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing a cross-threading issue.

This code block accesses the none-thread safe `List<T>` which can lead to unpredictable and none deterministic errors:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
         ...
    }));
```

You need to lock the tasks.Add call:

```
lock(tasks)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        ...
      }));
}
```